# Express/Socket.io: The right way for one socket per request

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I'm trying to build a simple Node app using Express, Socket.io, and the ntwitter module so you can just search for a term (that's req.params.searchTerm below) and ntwitter will search for it and output the stream via socket.io.

I'm running into errors, though, with multiple windows open, or closing a window and then opening a window immediately afterwards. Sometimes the search term is not updated, sometimes some kind of socket.io error is actually thrown. Could someone clarify the right way to do this or shed some light to my error? Thanks in advance. Code below.

```
var server = http.createServer(app);

var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
});

app.get('/:stream', function(req, res) {
 res.render('stream', { title: 'Search Twitter | ' + req.params.searchTerm });
    io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {

    var publishFlag = true;
    setInterval(function() {
        publishFlag = true;
    }, 1000);

    twit.stream('statuses/filter', { track: [req.params.searchTerm] },
        function(stream) {
            stream.on('data', function(tweet) {
                if(publishFlag) {
                    socket.emit('tweet', tweet);
                    publishFlag = false;
                }
            });
        }
    );
  });
});
```

Comment: I think the socket.io events should be managed outside of your res.render callback. As it is now, each time someone loads page `/:stream`, you set socket.io's onconnection event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It think that is somewhat what you are trying to do :

Server side :

```
var server = http.createServer(app);

var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
});

app.get('/:stream', function(req, res) {
 res.render('stream', { title: 'Search Twitter | ' + req.params.searchTerm });
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {

    socket.on('stream', function(searchTerm){

        twit.stream('statuses/filter', { track: [searchTerm] },
            function(stream) {
                stream.on('data', function(tweet) {
                    socket.emit('tweet', tweet);
                });
            }
        );
    };
});
```

client side (/:stream)

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
socket.on('tweet', addTweetOnPage);
socket.emit('stream', searchTerm);
```

Comment: thanks a ton - I'm going to give it a quick try before I give you the green checkmark. Makes sense now. It didn't occur to me to have the client emit('stream', searchTerm)

Comment: I think what you were trying to achieve was to have the server subscribe for the client when answering the client's request, except the server has no knowledge of which request is associated with which socket.io client. That is why you need the client to subscribe using his socket.

Comment: I wrote this off the top of my head, so it's probably not flawless

Comment: Thanks - it was actually pretty spot on. Thanks again for unblocking me! I didn't have an accurate understanding of socket.io